# Definition of division algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition

The definition on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algebra) of a division algebra $D$ is given as:

Given $a,b \in D$, $b \neq 0$ there exists a unique $c\in D$: $a = bc$ and a unique $d \in D$: $a = db$.

My question(s) are: What exactly does this mean and is it equivalent to this:

For all $a,b \in D$: if $ab = 0$ then either $a=0$ or $b=0$?

**Edit** Say we assume it's associative.

$\textbf{Edit}^2$: I am so confused! In some places it is defined to be a vector space of a field (with additional properties) and in some places it is defined to be a field in which multiplication does not commute.

Comment: The statement "For all $a,b \in D$: if $ab = 0$ then either $a=0$ or $b=0$." implies it is an integral domain (could be commutative) - that is no non-zero zero divisors. What you are looking for is the invertability property. You can see division algebra as a field with the commutative property removed. The term "algebra" comes in because, it can be seen as a vector space over its center and also as a ring.

Comment: @Shash, it does not *imply* that it is an integral domain, it means *precisely* that.

Comment: @Shash Division algebras don't have to be associative.

Comment: @Mariano and Matt, agreed

Comment: @Shash But looking at [this definition on Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivisionAlgebra.html) I looks like indeed it should not have zero divisors.

Comment: An associative division algebra will certainly not have zero divisors. An associative ring without zero divisors is called a domain. There are domains that aren't division algebras, and there are division algebras which aren't associative and aren't domains.

Comment: @rschwieb isn't the definition of division algebra on Wolfram really the definition of a domain?

Comment: @learner I don't see "is a ring without nonzero zero divisors" anywhere, so NO, I do not see any definition of "domain" there.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not equivalent. For example, a polynomial álgebra k[X] satisfies your condition but not Wikipedia's.

Comment: Okay, so the condition does not say "there are no zero divisors". But is there a translation of it into plain English?

Comment: Every element has a unique left and right inverse?

Comment: But [this definition here](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/octonions/node2.html) defines it to be an algebra without zero divisors.

Comment: And also this [definition on Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivisionAlgebra.html)... or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Okay, if I use the definition in Wikipedia then it means "an algebra over a field in which division is possible". But I'm still confused (see my edit in the question)